# ¿Por qué al achicar la ventana se come o desaparecen los componentes internos como los jpanels y los labels por ejemplo?

Tags: java, ventana

No entiendo qué produce este error, estoy tratando de usar este código en otro programa para redimensionar las ventanas desde los bordes y vértices hechos a base de JPanels, pero cuando achico la ventana se los come o desaparece lo que está dentro.

Adjunto una foto con casi todo el código, un video y dejo el código completo en drive para ver si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar el problema porque no sé qué podría ser.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1H1pGRHqywbwdVqZMW_8jfCyGYvK_JE/view?usp=sharing

```
                public static Dimension tamañoPantalla() {
                Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Rectangle sizePantallaRec = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
                Dimension sizePantalla = new Dimension(sizePantallaRec.width, sizePantallaRec.height);
                return sizePantalla;
            }        
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JFrame frame = new sized();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                      }
                });
            }
          }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: intenté hacerlo como me pedía la página pero por más que tenía comentarios el código, siempre me decía que era mucho código y poco contexto. Me terminó cansando aunque le pasaba borrando partes del código y lo publiqué así. Igual gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Recuerda siempre que debe ser un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_). Aún así, no te preocupes si pegas el código sin formato. Se puede dar formato luego de una edición :)